# Interactive notification support iOS 8

Tags: ios, xcode, ios8

I have an existing application that supports both local and push notifications, with the introduction of iOS 8 and its newly added features ([link](http://www.iphonehacks.com/2014/09/ios-8-interactive-notifications.html) referred) ,i thought of adding some of the features in app. My question is how to use interactive notification feature in my app.should i add any new framework; coding or an any tutorial link would be helpful. Also help me creating widgets for my app.

Comment: Read the documentation!

Comment: can u share me the link @dasdom

Comment: Are you serious? The link to the iOS developer documentation is this: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/navigation/index.html . I assumed every iOS developer has this in the favorites bar of their browser. What you are searching for is a user notification. Learn to read the docs. There is a lot of good information in there.

Comment: sorry for that i was using my friends machine

Answer (score 2):

This video helped me
https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2014/#713

and this link about notifications UI guidelines too
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/NotificationCenter.html

and this link for widgets
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/NotificationCenter.html